# I need help using cronjob

Tags: cron

I'm trying to write a cron job to run automatically a PHP file after 30 days. The PHP file has write permission 777.

Here is my code:

```
* * * */30 * php -f  /var/www/virtual/my_domain_name.com/htdocs/./file.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But this is not working, I got no errors.

When i try:

```
* * * * * php -f  /var/www/virtual/my_domain_name.com/htdocs/./file.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The script works, then it executes the file every second from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have `..././...` in the path to your PHP file? Why do you set its permission to `777`, which gives every user on the system permission to modify it? `755` is much more secure.

Comment: 1. i have ../../.. because thats de real path of my php file? It is stored on this path. Okay i set back the permissions on 755 i think also its mutch better. I dont want, that everyone has de right to edit that file. It include mysql connect data :/

Comment: The `/./` is redundant; `.` simply refers to the current directory. It's simpler and clearer (and absolutely equivalent) to refer to the file as `/var/www/virtual/my_domain_name.com/htdocs/file.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `*/30` in the 4th field would cause the job to run only in the 30th month of the year, and every 30 months thereafter during the year -- i.e., never.

Putting `*/30` in the 3rd field (day of month) would cause it to run on the 30th day of each month (and on the 60th, 90th, ... day of the month if there were such a thing). And given the `*`s in the other fields, it would run once a minute on that day -- and never in February. I doubt that that's what you want.

If you want a job to run once a month, that's easy:

```
 0 0 12 * * php ...
```

This will run the job at midnight on the 12th day of each month. Adjust the first two fields to pick a different time and the third to pick a different day.

There is no syntax for running a job once every 30 days. If that's really what you want,  you can schedule the job to run once every day:

```
 0 0 * * * php ...
```

and then have the job itself determine whether the current day is a multiple of 30.

Comment: I have a mysql tabel called "misch_sqlcmd". This table automatically stored temp data of my website registered users. I have write a php script "file.php" that delete this table. Now i want a cron that execute this file automatically every 14 days or 30 days. Do you understand what i mean ???

Comment: @JeffSergeKugener: Yes, I understand what you mean. Did you understand my answer? `cron` by itself cannot run a job every 14 or 30 days; there is no syntax to specify that. It can run a job every day, and the job itself can decide whether it should do anything. You can either add that logic to the PHP file, or you can write a wrapper script that invokes the PHP file. (Or you can run the job once or twice per calendar month if that meets your requirements.)

Comment: Okay i thought a cron was more easyier as a PHP script :/ Sorry i try it with a PHP wrapper

Comment: @JeffSergeKugener: I'm not at all sure what you mean by "i thought a cron was more easyier as a PHP script", but I'm glad I could help. If you're going to write a wrapper script that checks whether your PHP script should run or not, that wrapper doesn't have to be written in PHP, though of course it can be if that's what you're most comfortable with.